# R: subset data.frame by another vector

Tags: r, filter, subset

I have a dataframe with 241 rows. It is called master and it looks like this:

```
Patient   Sample   PDMax   FileName
1         1.1      6       GSM1
1         1.2      6       GSM2
2         2.1      8       GSM3
3         3.1      5       GSM4
3         3.2      7       GSM5
```

Now I have a vector called Biopsy with the important samples. I would like to subset the master dataframe, so that only the important informations are left.
This is the vector biopsy:

```
1.2  2.1  3.2
```

The result should be like this:

```
Patient   Sample   PDMax   FileName
1         1.2      6       GSM2
2         2.1      8       GSM3
3         3.2      7       GSM5
```

How can I do that? I tried different things like merge() or subset(), but everything failed.
Thanks!

Comment: Try `master[master$Sample %in% Biopsy,]`.

Comment: That doesn't work. The datatable which results is empty. What else can I do? @Lamia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the data wrangling verbs inside `dplyr`. Hadley Wickham's book is a great place to start (http://r4ds.had.co.nz/transform.html#filter-rows-with-filter)

```
library (dplyr)
master %>% filter(Sample %in% Biopsy)
```